# Associations HasMany works but HasOne does not

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I have two models defined in GraphQL Cars and Brands (their association is cars.brand_id = brands.id).
The schema only works when I define:

```
Cars.hasMany(models.brands, {
 sourceKey: 'brand_id',
 foreignKey: 'id'
})
```

Whereas it doesn't work if I define it in the following way:

```
Cars.hasOne(models.brands, {
 sourceKey: 'brand_id',
 foreignKey: 'id'
}),
```

Here I share a bit more of the schema (I am using makeExecutableSchema to split the files definitions):

Associations:

CarBrands.js

```
  CarBrands.associate = models => {
    CarBrands.hasOne(models.cars, {
    foreignKey: 'brand_id',
    });
  }
```

Cars.js

```
  Cars.associate = models => {
    Cars.belongsTo(models.brands),
    Cars.hasMany(models.car_images, {
        foreignKey: {
          name: 'car_id',
          allowNull: false
        },
        onDelete: "cascade"
    });
  };
```

Car Model:

```
export const typeDef = `
    type Cars {
        user_id: Int!,
        title: String!,
        brands: [CarBrands!],
        car_images: [CarImages],
    }
`;
```

The SQL is well-formed, and car_images returns the data correctly whereas brands does not. Any idea why is that?
Any hint will be forever appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the document **one-to-one-relationships** at there: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#one-to-one-relationships
.In the document introduces 4 options to define one-to-one.

Try it:

```
Brands.hasOne(Cars, {
  foreignKey: 'brand_id'
});
Cars.belongsTo(Brands);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did test this but it didn't work. I spend a long time trying to find the issue yet nothing works. I added more code now, as you see the car_images query returns the data correctly, yet brands does not, any idea why is that the case? (The SQL is well-formed).